# blackberry 6: getTimezoneOffset

Tags: javascript, blackberry

in my blackberry 6 widget I try to use following JavaScript-Code to calculate timezone of the client.

```
var tiz = -(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
```

[Here](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dy3ice.html) you can find online example.

Unfortunately BB6 calculates only 0.

May be someone has an idea what's the matter here or maybe suggests code that works better on BB6.

Thanks in advance!

Daniel

Comment: have you tried your code elsewhere?

Comment: What does Date().getTimezoneOffset() return?

Comment: And what timezone is your blackberry set to? (I.e. What do you *expect* it to return?)

Comment: This works correctly on my BB (displaying the same non-zero value as my desktop browser).

Comment: I basically tried the code on BB6 simulators and thought it's simulators' bug. But today I found out that a real (not simulator) BB 9700 with OS 6 on it don't like it either. The time Zone on the phones set to CET and the right string would be Your time zone is: 2. BB6 gets only 0.

Comment: just got link to the same issue on the BB-Dev-Forum:  http://is.gd/ZFkEfF

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known BB6 issue](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Javscript-GMT-Offfset-not-working-in-BB6-0-Devices-Non-Torch/td-p/815883). And it seems that there is an update to fix this issue.